# Access long key from meta-data from AndroidManifeast.xml

Tags: android, metadata, android-manifest

I implemented the following code and want to access the `key` meta-data value as a `Long` integer from the `MetaActivity.java` class.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.slk.metachecking"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<application>
    <meta-data android:name="key" android:value="488659867867350" />
</application>
```

**MetaActivity.java**

```
ApplicationInfo ai = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(),
                        PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
Bundle metaData = ai.metaData;

metaData.getString("key");  // Returns -36235050
metaData.getLong("key");  // Returns 0
```

Does Android support `long` as a type in meta-data tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element.html, as you can see only getInt is supported, so if you want to specify long value set it as a string (for example L123456789123456789) and parse it as a substring(1)